# E-mail subjects with or without articles?

Tags: article, letter

Would you say an e-mail subject is like a headline in a newspaper and thus we don't use articles in it or not?

So, is it:

> Textvorlage für neue Fußzeile

or:

> Textvorlage für die neue Fußzeile

Comment: Note that in German there is a difference between [*E-Mail*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/E-Mail) (engl. *e-mail*) and [*Email*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Email) (engl. *enamel*). The latter is a colored or whitish glassy coating. Assuming that you mean e-mail, I corrected your post accordingly.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I don't think many ppl know this alternative (less common) spelling. For me it's always been _Emaille_.

Comment: That's not the point. Irrespective of which word you prefer, *Emaille* or *Email*, both refer only to the coating. None is an alternative spelling for *E-Mail*, which must be hyphenated (in German).

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich But the post is in English, not German. So why should the German spelling matter here?

Answer (score 2):

These are both natural and I would understand both of them, neither seems obviously better than the other. I would not notice the difference if someone used one or the other.